# How to setup a Host-Only network for RPi

Tags: networking, windows, noobs

So i did a blind install of NOOBS on my new Raspberry Pi and can confirm it is functional, having connected it to my router and ssh to it from my PC.

I would like to setup something like a host-only network between my PC and the RPi, so i can directly connect using an ethernet cable. I've checked a lot of sources, most of which describe setting up a DHCP server on the PC for this purpose.

I've set the Obtain IP address / DNS automatically, enabled internet sharing and tried netstat, nmap, random ip address pings to detect the RPi but no luck so far.

Any ideas on how i can set this up? PC runs Windows 8 x64

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method to enable direct Ethernet connection to a PC is to assign a `static` IP address to the Pi. There are lots of tutorials/posts on this.

If you want the Pi to have Internet access you need to enable Internet Connection Sharing (or set up bridge mode) on the PC.

If you have a router connection via the network is the simplest, most flexible and reliable method.

Comment: I needed to edit the cmdline.txt file to add the static ip address. I did so by opening the boot.tar.xz via 7-zip and editing inside - Need to check if that'll work